# Angular badge - Change Shape as length increases

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material badge and I want the shape to be full circle if the content is single or double digit/character 
[image]
and grow into a rectangle with curved edges (like android/iPhone icon badges). However I am either getting an ellipsis [image]as the badge content grows or I can have it is a rectangle with curved edges for small values [image] and it grows in shape as the content increases.[image]

This is the .mat-badge-content css

```
{
  width: auto;
    display: grid;
    min-width: 22px;
    min-height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2px;
    // border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Please suggest how I can get the desired behaviour in Angular badge. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You just need `width: auto;` and `border-radius: 13px;` Border radius needs to be half of the total height including padding, which by default is 26px (22px height plus 2 * 2px padding). But the problem will be that the badge will expand leftward and might obscure content, so you need to change the `right` property as well.

```
.stretch-badge > .mat-badge-content {
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 13px;
  right: unset !important;
}
```

With this added to your global style, you can apply it to a badge's parent component:

```
<span matBadge="stretch badge" class="stretch-badge">Text with a stretched badge</span>
```

[image]

If you change font size or padding etc. - anything that makes the badge have a different size - you may need to adjust the border radius.

Answer (score 0):

How about dynamically adding a class to change the border-radius/width of the badge if the badge numbers become more than a certain length?

E.g. your html

```
<span [ngClass]="badgeCount > 99 ? 'override' : ''" class="badge mat-badge-content" *ngIf="badgeCount > 0">{{badgeCount}}</span>
```

Which would apply the class `override` if the count becomes more than 99, i.e. becomes 3 digits (I'll let you tweak this).

And add the following css:

```
.override {
  width: inherit !important;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

See the StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-badge-ejf6zs).